# Assign n number of rows distinct value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with 2 columns, **Digits** and **Random_Score** that looks like this:

```
Digits    Random_Score
000000         31 
000001         131  
000002         132   
000003         74
```

Column Digits contains all combination of numbers from 0 to 9 of length 6, so I have 10^6 rows in total. Currently, I want to create a new column **Number** such that, first 10000 rows will have a value of 1, next 10000 rows 2, and so on for the entire dataframe. Final pandas dataframe should look like this:

```
Digits     Random_Score  Number 
000000           31       1
000001           131      1
000002           132      1
.
.
.
999999           74      100
```

I have tried using iterrows to solve this problem, but I didn't manage to get far so I'm not including my code in the submission. Can you guys give me any suggestions?

Comment: Use `df['Number'] = df.index//10000` (if normal range as index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use integer division by `10000` and add `1`:

```
np.random.seed(123)

N = 1000000
d = {
    'Digits': np.arange(N),
    'Random_Score': np.random.randint(100, size=N),
}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df['Digits'] = df['Digits'].astype(str).str.zfill(6)
```

---

```
#if default RangeIndex
#df['Number'] = df.index // 10000 + 1

#any index
df['Number'] = np.arange(len(df)) // 10000 + 1


print (df)
        Digits  Random_Score  Number
0       000000            66       1
1       000001            92       1
2       000002            98       1
3       000003            17       1
4       000004            83       1
       ...           ...     ...
999995  999995            36     100
999996  999996            76     100
999997  999997            54     100
999998  999998            76     100
999999  999999            43     100

[1000000 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: Accurate way of doing it, nice answer.